# Spring Boot context initialization error when run application's main() method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix

I'm trying out a **Hystrix** sample app and everything works fine if I run the application using maven command `mvn spring-boot:run` but if I try to run the application's `main()` method, there are bunch of errors and application context won't initialize.

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hystrixCommandAspect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2c13da15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at me.lakmal.moviecatalogservice.MovieCatalogServiceApplication.main(MovieCatalogServiceApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2c13da15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I'm wondering what is the difference between running application's `main()` method and `mvn spring-boot:run` which could cause for this issue.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Looks like the dependencies in your IDE haven't been refreshed compared to running it on the commandline.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, but I refreshed the project dependencies through the IDE as well.

Comment: Different JDK? Borked dependency jar? Or somehow different dependencies for some reason (using different maven version in the IDE and command-line?).

Comment: Using the same JDK and Maven versions, noticed that these errors will go away if I add some additional dependencies like aspectjrt, aspectjweaver and spring-aspects  but after that application behave unexpectedly.